# Does chrome support "addEventListener"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I use chrome to test the Cross-browser event handling, the function does not work.It says that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". As far as I know, chrome support the "addEventListener" function, but it can't identify the function. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>event test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var EventUtil = {
        addHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.addEventListener){
                element.addEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.attachEvent){
                element.attachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = handler;
            }
        },
        removeHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.removeEventListener){
                element.removeEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.detachEvent){
                element.detachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = null;
            }
        }
    };
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    var handler1 = function(){
        alert("Hello!");
    };
    EventUtil.addHandler(btn,"click",handler1);
</script>
<input type="button" name="mybutton" id="myBtn" value="myButton">
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with the code? How to fix it?

Comment: Yes it does support, wrap code in [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or move it to the bottom of `body`

Comment: The problem is your script is placed before the dom element, either place your script after the element or wait for the dom to be ready - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"` means that you are trying to do `null.addEventListener`. I.e. the issue is with what populates `btn`, not with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the input tag is placed under the script tag, the code will get excuted before the element is created so nothing will work. You can fix this by placing the script tag under the input tag or adding window.onload(){\here goes your instruction}, in which you can just put what you need to excute, you can initialize function in any place but this is where you call them

Answer (score 1):

Execute your javascript code after page load or place it at the end of the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>event test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="mybutton" id="myBtn" value="myButton">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var EventUtil = {
        addHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.addEventListener){
                element.addEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.attachEvent){
                element.attachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = handler;
            }
        },
        removeHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.removeEventListener){
                element.removeEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.detachEvent){
                element.detachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = null;
            }
        }
    };
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    var handler1 = function(){
        alert("Hello!");
    };
    EventUtil.addHandler(btn,"click",handler1);
</script>
</html>
```

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var EventUtil = {
        addHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.addEventListener){
                element.addEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.attachEvent){
                element.attachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = handler;
            }
        },
        removeHandler : function(element, type, handler){
            if (element.removeEventListener){
                element.removeEventListener(type,handler,false);
            }else if (element.detachEvent){
                element.detachEvent("on" + type,handler);
            }else{
                element["on" + type] = null;
            }
        }
    };
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    var handler1 = function(){
        alert("Hello!");
    };
    EventUtil.addHandler(btn,"click",handler1);
  };
</script>
```